# Coroutine Channel in Extension Class does not send or receive data

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have been working with kotlin and coroutines lately and I am trying to implement a channel in an extension class of a Fragment Class. To explain myself better:

**MapFragment.kt** --> Fragment Class which calls functions sendFunction() and receiveFunction() when a button is clicked.

**MapFunctionality.kt** --> Extends the MapFragment class. Here are both functions sendFunction() and receiveFunction() implemented.

**MapFragment.kt**

```
open class MapFragment : Fragment(), PermissionsListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mymapView.onResume()
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener {
            MapFunctionality().receiveFun()
            MapFunctionality().sendFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

**MapFunctionality.kt**

```
class MapFunctionality : MapFragment(), CoroutineScope {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main

    private val getAllPointsChannel = Channel<MutableList<Point>>()

    fun sendFunction(){
        launch(coroutineContext) {
            testChannel.send("Hello")
            println("Message sent")
        }
    }

    fun receiveFun(){
        launch(coroutineContext) {
            println("about to receive a message")
            val a = testChannel.receive()
            println("$a")
        }
}
```

The output will just be

*"about to receive a message"*

If I implement the functions in the MapFragment.kt class, then it works fine.

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Why do you use the `Default` dispatcher instead of `Main`? 2. The things you do with `coroutineContext` and `CoroutineScope` look pretty messed up. You should follow the usual guidelines instead.

Comment: I just tried using the Main, but it didn't make any difference. Also not defining a specific CoroutineScope also did not solve the problem.

Comment: Where is `testChannel` declared? It doesn't seem scoped to just one interaction between `sendFunction` and `receiveFunction`. Also you declare a `getAllPointsChannel`, but you don't use it. It's scoped to a single `MapFunctionality` instance, but your calling code instantiates this class for every invocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code it looks like you instantiate your `MapFunctionality` class twice, which would mean that you end up with two instances with each of their own `Channel`.

Is the below correct?

```
MapFunctionality().receiveFun()
MapFunctionality().sendFunction()
```

I believe you should do this instead:

```
val mapfun = MapFunctionality()
mapfun.receiveFun()
mapfun.sendFunction()
```